# Tool for measuring html5 performance(YSlow or PageSpeed)

Tags: html, performance, pagespeed

I developed several html5 pages and wanted to find out an efficient tool measuring those pages performance.

Did anybody know among YSlow and PageSpeed which is the best to do so? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO!!!

First of all, SO avoids questions which are about tool recommendation, code review etc. 
As you are new to SO I'll provide you my opinion but before asking such questions you should use google, your knowledge first.

Both are browser plugins which will tell you analysis of website based on some standard set performance parameters.

**YSlow** : Gives rating based results, generally it shows what are the problems. It has database of websites which are better optimized and it ranks website against those benchmarks.

Con : It shows what are the problems but it doesn't provide a solution to it

**Pagespeed** : Google product. Very good for performance and usability perspective. It not only rates your website but it also tells you performance issues on your website categorically.

Good things ,

1. categorical view of perf issues i.e. High, medium, low
2. Best thing about it is, it provides solution to those problems upto some extent.

IMHO, Pagespeed is better than YSlow.